# Why can't my elements be arranged on one line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got stuck on making ingredients in one line. 5 elements in my projects(4 texts and one image) should be on one line but one keeps getting out of it.

[image]

here's my code.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "레시피코리아OTF";
    src: url(RecipeKorea.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "나눔스퀘어";
    src: url(NanumSquareL.otf);
}

body {
    background-color: #ff6f61;
}

#profile {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -68px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    filter: invert(100%);
}

#logo {
    font-family: "레시피코리아OTF";
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;
}

#menu1, #menu2, #menu3 {
    font-family: "나눔스퀘어";
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>포네그리프 홈</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./animereview.html" id="menu1">애니메이션 리뷰</a></li>
            <li><a href="./mangarevie.html" id="menu2">만화 리뷰</a></li>
            <li><a href="./detailedsearch.html" id="menu3">세부 검색</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="./home.html" id="logo">포네그리프</a>
        <a href="profile.html"><img id="profile" src="user.png"></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried as far as I can. I turned each elements into float, inline-block, changing margin size... but nothing worked. The picture above is the closest one to my plan.

Comment: your UL is a block element.

Comment: Protip: Don't use floats for layout. They're outdated and troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

For stuff like this, you should look into using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) instead of using (inline-)block. [Here is a handy visual tool](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv/) to play around with Flex.

For example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="column col1">
        <div class="item">Item 1.1</div>
        <div class="item">Item 1.2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column col2">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="column col3">
        Item 3
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: 100% agree. Flexbox is the way to go here, far easier to work with and more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand [image: output] you want to be output like this.

First I move your last two a tag in list also so the html structure is something like that

```
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./animereview.html" id="menu1">애니메이션 리뷰</a></li>
    <li><a href="./mangarevie.html" id="menu2">만화 리뷰</a></li>
    <li><a href="./detailedsearch.html" id="menu3">세부 검색</a></li>
    <li><a href="./home.html" id="logo">포네그리프</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="profile.html"
        ><img
          id="profile"
          src="https://img.freepik.com/free-psd/engraved-black-logo-mockup_125540-223.jpg?w=2000"
      /></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and after that I added flex in to list.

```
.parent > ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

Also there are no need these margin part on your CSS

```
#profile {
    float: right;
    /* margin-top: -68px;
    margin-right: 30px; */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    filter: invert(100%);
  }
```

I would recommend to you work on your CSS skills more, I make minor changes on your CSS code but there are still some parts can make a problem in the future. Especially you can look for flexbox usage.